# Imported 3D objects do not appear on gameplay with ARTOOLKIT on Unity

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, artoolkit

I am making a simple Unity application for android using artoolkit. I have tried many methods but none of them work. I place the object and/or 3Ds objects on the marker and they still fail to show up in gameplay. I put regular objects from unity by selecting new-->3D Object-->Cube and the cube shows up but the 3DS/obj object does not.

To double check if the orientation is wrong, I even put the objects halfway thru the marker tag.

Some images explaining my situation better:

- [What the project in Unity looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOsVl.png)
- [The end result on the Android device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lWeaJ.jpg)

How can I fix this?

Comment: Which layers are "Heart" and "Cube" on?

Comment: they are on the at marker. both of them and just the cube shows up

Comment: I mean which Unity Layer ("Default", "AR Background", "AR Foreground", etc... ) is the cube on? And which is the Heart on?  If the cube was from the example, it will be on one of the "AR Background" or "AR Foreground" layers - if you added the heart to that example but did not assign it to the correct layer, it would not work properly.

Comment: Edit > Project Settings > "Tags and Layers" in my version of unity (5.5.1).